# N(T) of T(A) =tr(A) why is the nullity n^2 -1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

This is the question I'm trying to solve: [The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmsI3.png)

And this is its answer for the N(t): [Finding the N(T) Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6lej.png)

I was wondering here how does
$$ S= {E^{ij} : 1<=i, j<=n} $$
translates to The nxn matrix whose ijth entry is 1 and all other entries are 0.
Where did we get that the entry is equal to 1?

Comment: That's the definition of $E^{ij}$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $S = \{E^{ij}: 1\leq i,j \leq n\}$ simply means that $S$ is the set of all matrices $E^{ij}$, where $i$ and $j$ are integers from $1$ to $n$. Contrary to what your question implies, this statement does **not** translate to "$E^{ij}$ is the nxn matrix whose ijth entry is 1 and all other entries are 0".

We are supposed to infer the nature of $E^{ij}$ from the statement that $S$ is the "standard basis for $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb F)$". Because this isn't a very clear description, the author added the explicit parenthetical explanation that "$E^{ij}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$".